# Q: Error Code: 1292 Truncated incorrect datetime value for varchar parameter, only in prodecure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

So... I had a stored procedure that is supposed to return gravity form data from a mySQL database. It was running, but I had some issues with null values. After correcting those, it now tells me, when I try to run the stored procedure, that I have a "truncated incorrect datetime value" for my input parameter which is the person's login ID, and defined as varchar(8). It originally worked, and it works in a standard query call (with variables being renamed with an "@"). Any ideas?

Here's the stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `wp_GetWeeklyReport`(
IN aID varchar(8),
OUT formnumb int,
OUT rptDate date
)
BEGIN

DECLARE ltstAgtEnt int;
# Finds the last entry number for the user login passed by parameter, returns 0 if none found
SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT max(entry_id)
FROM pkwp_gf_entry_meta 
 WHERE form_id = 19 AND meta_key = 38 AND meta_value = aID 
 GROUP BY form_id, meta_key, meta_value) THEN (SELECT max(entry_id)
FROM pkwp_gf_entry_meta 
 WHERE form_id = 19 AND meta_key = 38 AND meta_value = aID 
 GROUP BY form_id, meta_key, meta_value)
 ELSE 0
 END)
INTO ltstAgtEnt;
 # returns the latest entry date for any submitted form of this type
SELECT max(pkwp_gf_entry_meta.meta_value) INTO rptDate
 FROM pkwp_gf_entry_meta 
 WHERE form_id = 19 AND meta_key = 3 
 GROUP BY form_id, meta_key;
 # returns the entry number for this user if their last entry matches the latest date
SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT entry_id
FROM pkwp_gf_entry_meta 
WHERE entry_id = ltstAgtEnt AND meta_value = rptDate) THEN (SELECT entry_id
FROM pkwp_gf_entry_meta 
WHERE entry_id = ltstAgtEnt AND meta_value = rptDate)
ELSE 0
END)
INTO formnumb;

END
```

Here's the execution call:

```
set @formnumb = 0;
set @rptDate = '0';
call wordpressdb.wp_GetWeeklyReport('SMITBILL', @formnumb, @rptDate);
select @formnumb, @rptDate;
```

And the result:

```
10:36:30    call wordpressdb.wp_GetWeeklyReport('SMITBILL', @formnumb, @rptDate)    Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect datetime value: 'YANGCHIA'    0.141 sec
```

However, if I build a query instead of a stored procedure -

```
SET @aID = 'SMITBILL';

SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT max(entry_id)
FROM pkwp_gf_entry_meta 
 WHERE form_id = 19 AND meta_key = 38 AND meta_value = @aID 
 GROUP BY form_id, meta_key, meta_value) THEN (SELECT max(entry_id)
FROM pkwp_gf_entry_meta 
 WHERE form_id = 19 AND meta_key = 38 AND meta_value = @aID 
 GROUP BY form_id, meta_key, meta_value)
 ELSE 0
 END)
INTO @ltstAgtEnt;

SELECT max(pkwp_gf_entry_meta.meta_value) INTO @rptdate
 FROM pkwp_gf_entry_meta 
 WHERE form_id = 19 AND meta_key = 3 
 GROUP BY form_id, meta_key;

SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT entry_id
FROM pkwp_gf_entry_meta 
WHERE entry_id = @ltstAgtEnt AND meta_value = @rptdate) THEN (SELECT entry_id
FROM pkwp_gf_entry_meta 
WHERE entry_id = @ltstAgtEnt AND meta_value = @rptdate)
ELSE 0
END)
INTO @formnumb;

SELECT @formnumb, @rptdate;
```

We get -

```
formnumb  rptdate
3126    2020-04-03
```

Comment: The error is from a call to procedure wp_Get**AgentWeekly** , we should probably look at the code in that procedure.  The code dump given here is for a different procedure, named wp_Get**WeeklyReport**.

Comment: I changed the name when I posted the code (I generally do a better job of not revealing too much proprietary information), it's the same report. - I just changed the message to match. The code you need is there.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the output variable to varchar(10) allows the stored procedure to run, but if anyone has insight on why it worked, at first, and why it works as a query but not stored procedure, "Best Answer" rights are up for grabs.